# Read/Write SharePoint User Field [Word 2010 VSTO]

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, vsto, sharepoint-2013

I've been experimenting with reading SharePoint 2013 Site Column metadata from within a Word 2010 Application-level C# VSTO.

For testing I've set-up Site Columns for every type that SharePoint uses, then created a Document Content Type that ties to them all -- thus all these columns are embedded into the Word document (looks to be stored within customXml within the document file).

By reading from the `_Document.ContentTypeProperties` property within the VSTO's code, I can access most types, but I'm having difficulty accessing a 'Person or Group' Site Column's data -- I'm getting COM Exceptions attempting to read or write to an item's `.Value` property.

By looking at the XSD schema in customXml, I can see a single-value User column is made up of three values: `DisplayName` (type `string`), `AccountType` (type `string`) and `AccountId` (type `UserId`) -- however I don't see a way to read/write from/to this within the VSTO?  Multi-value User columns appear to be completely different, and are made up of two `string` values: an ID (appears to be the SharePoint user's ID) and a string-based ID (or at least that's what I think the `i:0#.w|domain\userid` is, anyway).

Word itself can edit both single- and multi-valued User column data via the Document Panel, but only if Word is currently connected to SharePoint -- otherwise the functionality is disabled.  I'd *assume* the same would be true for the VSTO, if I could access the values at all...

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to read/write single- and multi-value User fields from within VSTO code (even if it's not via the `_Document.ContentTypeProperties` property)?
2. Is there a way to do Q1 when if not connected to SharePoint (if, say, the values are known to the code)?

*(I've been somewhat overly verbose in case my workings so far are useful to someone else even if I get no answers; there doesn't seem to be a great amount of information about this anywhere)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some provisos, I believe you can do read/update these fields using VSTO - although I haven't actually created a working example using VSTO, the same objects as I'd use in Word VBA are available - the code snippets below are VBA.

The person/group values that are displayed in the DIP are stored in a Custom XML Part, even when the SharePoint server is unavailable. So the problem is not modifying the values - it's a CRUD operation, in essence - but knowing what values you can use, particularly in the multi-valued case. If you know how to construct valid values (let's say you have an independent list of email addresses) then you can make the modifications locally. Personally, I don't know how I would construct a valid value for the multi-valued case so I'd basically have to contact the server.

So assuming you have the data you need to update locally...

When SharePoint serves a Word Document, it inserts/updates several Custom XML Parts. One contains a set of schemas (as you have discovered). Another contains the data. All you really need to do is access the correct Custom XML Part, find the XML Element corresponding to your SharePoint user/group column, then it's a CRUD operation on the subElements of that Element.

You can find the correct Custom XML Part using the appropriate namespace name, e.g.

```
Const metaPropDataUri as String = _
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties"
Dim theDoc as Word.Document
Dim cxp as Office.CustomXMLPart 
Dim cxps as Office.CustomXMLParts 
Set theDoc = ActiveDocument
Set cxps = theDoc.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(metaPropDataUri)
```

If there is more than one part associate with that Namespace, I don't know for sure how to choose the correct one. AFAIK Word/Sharepoint only ever creates one, and experiments suggest that if there is another one, SharePoint works with the first one. So I use

```
Set cxp = cxps(1)
```

At this point you need to know the XML Element name of the person/group column. It may be the same as the external name (the one you can see in the SharePoint list), but if for example someone called the Sharepoint column "person group", the Element name will be "person_x0020_group". If the name isn't going to vary, you can get it from the schema XML as a one-off task. Or it may be easy to generate the correct element name from any given SharePoint name. Otherwise, you can get it dynamically from the Schema XML, which you can get (as a string) using

```
theDoc.ContentTypeProperties.SchemaXML
```

What you need to do then is find the  element with attribute ma:displayName="the external name" and get the value of the name attribute. I would imagine that's quite straightforward using c#, a suitable XML object, and a bit of XPath, say

```
//xsd:element[@ma:displayName='person group'][1]/@name
```

which should return 'person_x0020_group'

You can then get the Element node for your data, e.g. something along the lines of

```
Dim cxn As Office.CustomXMLNode
Set cxn = cxp.SelectSingleNode("//*[name()='person_x0020_group'][1]")
```

Or you may find it's preferable to get the namespace Uri of the Elements in this Custom XML Part and use that to help you locate the correct node. The name is a long hex string assigned by SharePoint. You can get it from the Schema XML using, e.g.

```
//xsd:schema[1]/@targetNamespace
```

Once you have your node, you would use the known structures (i.e. the ones you have found in the Schemas) to get/modify/create child nodes as required.

Comment: I was thinking I might have to directly modify the customXml data -- I was hoping I wouldn't need to just for one type, though.  I'll have a look into this -- thanks!

Comment: Yes, AFAICS there is no interface that exposes the internal structure of the ContentTypeProperty object for this type of Property.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort -- and while this is certainly looking like the only option available, I'd like to leave marking it 'correct' a short while in case another potential solution appears (you never know with VSTO stuff...).

Answer (score 0):

of course you can. You should use the SharePoint Client-side Object model (CSOM) to manipulate SharePoint data from a location away from the server. The only thing you will need is the URL of your SharePoint site.

You can then connect through CSOM like this:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("SITEURL");
Site site = context.Site;
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(site);
context.Load(web);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

See here an example to set a single user field:

First get the ID of the user through ensuring the username

```
u = context.Web.EnsureUser(UserOrGroupName);
context.Load(u);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To set the value, you can use this string format:

```
userid;#userloginname;#
```

To set the field use this:

```
item[myusercolumn] = "userid;#userloginname;#";
item.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To set a multi user field, you can use the same code, just use ;# to concat the different usernames, such as:

```
item[myusercolumn] = "userid1;#userloginname1;#userid2;#userloginname2;#userid3;#userloginname3;#";
item.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however your method is for changing the data on SharePoint directly, rather than the data contained within the Word document -- therefore when saving the document back to SharePoint, it'd surely overwrite any changes made using your approach?

Comment: Ok sorry, i misread your question. Then i can only say that in the 'stringbased id' like you call it, this is actually a claims encoded username. The prefix 'i:0#.w|' tells SharePoint if its a user or group (i or c) and which type of authentication is used (w: windows auth, f: formsbased)